# Variety not working in dark mode on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, desktop-background, 22.04, variety

hello update from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 but it turns out that after updating I have noticed that variety stopped working and no longer shows me my custom backgrounds in dark mode instead it shows me the Jammy Jellyfish main background.

[image: the folders are already configured]

[image: these images are supposed to be displayed]

[image: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Refuses to show my backgrounds in dark mode retaining the main background of Jammy Jellyfish]

How To Fix Variety Background Problem on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I have solved the problem I never knew that exclusive images for dark mode was a new feature in the end I had to use Variety (for light mode) and Shotwell for dark mode)

Answer (score 37):

You need to adjust a bit set_wallpaper script used by variety. Use this command to allow to change wallpapers in dark mode. By the way, since version 0.8.7, variety will do it automatically.

```
sed -i '/^# Gnome 3, Unity*/a gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file://$WP" 2> /dev/null' /home/$USER/.config/variety/scripts/set_wallpaper
```

The command will search '# Gnome 3, Unity' string in your ~/.config/variety/scripts/set_wallpaper script to add this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file://$WP" 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: you are hero. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm for me on Pop!_OS

Comment: this is making my desktop freeze, how do I undo this?

Comment: can someone please tell me how to revert this, it has really effed up my desktop

Comment: I think it would be really useful, if you could describe what this command actually changes in the script.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the solution! I got my Variety installed from the official Ubuntu 22.04 repo so it did not work in dark mode out of the box as reported here.

Comment: Haha... after re-installing my OS, and having the same problem, I googled and came across this answer... looking at my previous comment it worked for me before... It's just worked for me again :) Thanks. I'd upvote it again if I could...

Answer (score 1):

Was resolved in https://github.com/varietywalls/variety/releases/tag/0.8.7

So now you just need to install `variety` from official ppa and everything works out of the box.